# Python: Elegant way to increment a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, iterator, generator

> Elegant way to increment a global variable in Python:

This is what I have so far:

```
my_i = -1
def get_next_i():
    global my_i
    my_i += 1
    return my_i
```

with generator:

```
my_iter = iter(range(100000000)) 
def get_next_i():
    return next(my_iter)
```

with class:

```
class MyI:
    MyI.my_i = -1
    @staticmethod
    def next():
        MyI.my_i += 1
        return MyI.my_i
```

- The first one is long and I don't consider it as a better way to code .
- The second one is a bit more elegant, but have an upper limit.
- The third one is long, but at least have no global variable to work with.

**What would be the best alternative to those?**

> The purpose of these functions is to assign a unique number to a specific event in my code. The code is not just a single loop, so using `for i in range(...):` is not suitable here. A later version might use multiple indices assigned to different events. The first code would require duplication to solve such an issue. (`get_next_i()`, `get_next_j()`, ...)

Thank You.

Comment: Just use `itertools.count`?

Comment: "The third one is long, but at least have no global variable to work with" -- it does still have a global variable, it's just that it's spelled `my_module.MyI.my_i` instead of `my_module.my_i`. For the purpose of worrying about globals being dangerous, a global is something that can be accessed willy-nilly by anyone. None of the potential issues with globals go away just because you move it from the module namespace into a class namespace. You need to address the potential issues instead (or as well).

Comment: yes but you won't name your variable as `MyI.my_i` and ruin the functionality of the `next()` method. The first example is bad because writing a `for my_i in range(123):` will ruin the `get_next_i()` function.

Comment: @Dombi: Yes, "obviously" `for my_i in range(123:)` at module level re-assigns the global. But point taken: I don't write code like that at module level, but those who do will hit this problem. Those who write `for my_i in xrange(123):` at class level will hit the same problem with `MyI.my_i`, but I grant you that's even rarer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others suggested, `itertools.count()` is the best option, e.g.

```
import itertools

global_counter1 = itertools.count()
global_counter2 = itertools.count()
# etc.
```

And then, when you need it, simply call `next`:

```
def some_func():
    next_id = next(global_counter1)
```

**EDIT:** Changed `global_counter1.next()` (which worked only in Python 2) to `next(global_counter1)`, which works also in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a generator that has an infinite loop. Each call of `next(generator)` will return a next value, without limit. See [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python?rq=1)

```
def create_generator()
    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        yield i

generator = create_generator()
print(next(generator))
print(next(generator))
```

Comment: Or - just use `itertools.count` which does exactly this? (except with optional start and step arguments...)

Comment: `counts = {'i': count(), 'j': count(), 'k': count()}` - then access `next(counts['j'])` or `next(counts['k'])`  and keep `counts` accessible...

Comment: submit as an answer